# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after ~1 hour

Tags: 20.04

My Ubuntu completly freezes after about 1 hour of usage. This happens when I'm doing basic stuff on Ubuntu (editing files etc.) but also when I'm gaming. What exactly hapens is that first everything starts lagging (games lag, music lag, mouse moves choppy) and after about 10 seconds everything freezes (no music anymore, cursor doesn't move). I've to reboot my pc to get it fixed. Everytime I reboot the same freezing issue starts again after about 1 hour.

My system specs:

- I7-8700K
- MSI RX5700XT
- MSI Z370 Gaming Plus
- 32GB Ram 3200MHz

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. My video driver version is: 20.45-1164792 (according to dpkg -l amdgpu-pro )

I'm currently still running Windows as my main OS but planning to go to Linux in the future. I've no issues in Windows.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I'm getting constantly the error:

```
 23.12.20 00:36 gnome-shell [3595:3595:1223/003633.411413:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglGetMscRateANGLE: glXGetMscRateOML failed.
```

I've currently updated the amd drivers. But that didn't solve the issue Here is a link to the journal file [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZFpcJPM54X/)

Comment: Have you looked in the logs for reasons? A great GUI tool to do so is ksystemlog - `sudo apt install ksystemlog`.

Comment: `journalctl -b -1` might help after it crashed.... It will show the kernel logs of the previous boot - since i assume you had to restart after that crash

Comment: @KGIII When working normally KSystemlog is constantly spitting out this: 23.12.20 00:36 gnome-shell [3595:3595:1223/003633.411413:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(773)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglGetMscRateANGLE: glXGetMscRateOML failed. But after a quick google it looks like to be a bug in the amd driver. I'll try to see if there is a newer version

Comment: @kanehekili it opens the log but it is more than 1000 lines long, is it possible to do a tail of it?

Comment: I know nothing about AMD graphics drivers - but I'd edit your post to add that so that more people can see it and there are plenty of folks here who know more about it than I do. That's quite likely the reason you're getting the crashes.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning to edit the post. I've installed a slightly newer driver from the amd site, I don't see the error anymore in KSystemlog and hope the issue is solved with doing this. I'll try to confirm tomarrow if this solved the issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: Just use that command with `journalctl -b -1 | pastebin` and add that link to to your question. But it seems to be an AMD problem.. That is unknown terrain, since AMD did not help the Linux community for a long time. (It got better though ;-)). What does `lspci` say?

Comment: For some reason the pastebin doesn't work for me, I tried it with pastebin but gave me an error that the command pastebin wasn't found. Afterwards I installed `pastebinit` and did the command with `pastebinit` but now I'm getting the error: `Failed to contact the server: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway`. `03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev c1)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio` That's the output of `lspci` from my gpu

Comment: I managed to get a pastebin link. I've created 2: one fore the journal: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ft3kdTCxtx/) and one for `lspci`: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GWh9bf8Jjh/)

Comment: I just tested it and it freezed again after ~1 hour. I had Ksystemlog open and it showed something that my input was running behind and something that pulseaudio was overrunning or so, both where warnings. These warnings showed up when the freezes was alread ongoing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comming accidently up in the system monitor, I saw that there was a background program using about 16gb of memory, and keeps using more over time. This program is for my sound controller, I closed it and now and it didn't crash anymore. Thanks @Kanehkili and @KGIII for helping.